# error : 403 disallowed_useragent while authenticating with google using azure services

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, google-oauth

How to resolve the error 403 disallowed_useragent. The error is occuring while consuming windows azure mobile services of authentication with Google.
My code is

```
var user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var authAlert = new UIAlertView("Authentication", "You are now logged in " + user.UserId, null, "OK", null);
                        //authAlert.Show();
                    }
```